# Grails GORM conditional left outer join

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Say I have the following domain objects:

```
class Top {  
  User createdBy  
  Other other  
  static hasMany = [  
    children: Child,  
  ]  
}

class Child {
  User createdBy
  static belongsTo = [
    top: Top,
  ]
}
```

And given User myUser and Other myOther, I want to select all the Tops where

top.other.id = myOther.id AND
join all children if top.createdBy = myUser OR
if top.createdBy != myUser, join only the children where child.createdBy = myUser (or maybe no children)

Here's what I tried (amongst many other failed variations):

```
Top.createCriteria().list{
  eq('other', myOther)
  createAlias('children', 'c', JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
  children {
    or {
      isNull('c')
      eq('createdBy', myUser)
      and {
        ne('createdBy', myUser)
        eq('c.createdBy', myUser)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this fails with "org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: children" and a useless stack trace.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the "duplicate association path" error by doing the left join as shown below. and remove the alias

```
children(CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) {
    or {
     ........
  }
```

Not tested but try this

```
Top.createCriteria().list{
  eq('other', myOther)
  or {
    eq "createdBy", myUser
    children(CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) {
        eq "createdBy", myUser
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Tried this in `Grails 4.0.11` and it works. I have a case of 2 hasMany relations and the default inner join type resulted in an empty resultset. Using `children1(CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)` and `children2(CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) `  solved this.

Answer (score 0):

**For conditional inner join with Grails 3**

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions

...
...

Top.createCriteria().list{   
    eq('other', myOther)   
    createAlias('children', 'c', JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("c.createdBy", myUser))   

    ne('createdBy', myUser)

}
```

This will add condition at criteria level, and generate sql nearby identical to below one.

```
Select
...
...

left outer join
        child ch1_ 
            on top_.id=ch1_.id 
            and (
                ch1_.createdBy=? 
            ) 
where
 top_.createdBy <> ?
```